# how to umount from python script

Tags: python, subprocess, gksudo, umount

i want to umount a mounting point named VirtualDVD.
i want to run the command, "gksudo umount VirtualDVD"

My function is:

```
def umount(self):
    '''unmounts VirtualDVD'''
    cmd = 'gksudo umount VirtualDVD'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    print proc
```

i try "gksudo umount VirtualDVD" from terminal and everything is ok.

i try "gksudo umount VirtualDVD" from subprocess and it fails...
it pops up the gksudo dialog and i can enter my password, but then it seems that umount fails because the VirtualDVD still is mounted.
why?

Comment: It will be fine if your run your script from root in a first place

Comment: i don't want to run as root, i want every user can run it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out... i should umount with complete path of mounting point.
i changed the umount function as following and it works...

```
def umount(self):
    '''unmounts VirtualDVD'''
    #get virtualdvd folder
    home = QtCore.QDir.homePath()
    vpath = home + "/VirtualDVD"

    cmd = 'gksudo umount ' + vpath
    proc = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    print proc
```